# JSON C# Parsing Error

Tags: c#, json, linq, c#-4.0, json.net

This is my JSON

```
{
    "3659639": {
        "EventID": 3659639,
        "RaceNum": 2,
        "Meeting": "Newton Abbot",
        "RaceType": "T",
        "Description": "Attheraces.Com Handicap Chase",
        "Distance": "5300m",
        "TrackCondition": "Good",
        "Weather": "Overcast",
        "Abandoned": 0,
        "SuspendDateTime": "2014-06-17 00:00:42.0000000",
        "OutcomeDateTime": "2014-06-17 00:00:00.0000000",
        "EffectiveRaceDate": "2014-06-16",
        "Status": "Paying",
        "Results": [
            {
                "event_id": 3659639,
                "saddle_number": 11,
                "position": 1,
                "status": "Final"
            },
            {
                "event_id": 3659639,
                "saddle_number": 16,
                "position": 2,
                "status": "Final"
            },
            {
                "event_id": 3659639,
                "saddle_number": 17,
                "position": 3,
                "status": "Final"
            }
        ],
        "Dividends": {
            "0": {
                "event_id": 3659639,
                "source": "NSW",
                "pool_type": "Duet",
                "outcome": "11\/16",
                "pool_value": 79.5,
                "interim_dividend": 11.2,
                "final_dividend": 11.2
            },

            "36": {
                "event_id": 3659639,
                "source": "VIC",
                "pool_type": "Trifecta",
                "outcome": "11\/16\/17",
                "pool_value": 1733,
                "interim_dividend": 2746.2,
                "final_dividend": 2746.2
            },
            "37": {
                "event_id": 3659639,
                "source": "VIC",
                "pool_type": "Win",
                "outcome": "11",
                "pool_value": 2541.06,
                "interim_dividend": 25.5,
                "final_dividend": 25.5
            },
            "RunnerProducts": {
                "11": {
                    "TopeTotePlace": 12,
                    "MidTotePlace": 7.3,
                    "TopeToteWin": 29.8,
                    "MidToteWin": 28,
                    "BestOrSP": 29.8
                },
                "16": {
                    "TopeTotePlace": 2.3,
                    "MidTotePlace": 2
                },
                "17": {
                    "TopeTotePlace": 26.4,
                    "MidTotePlace": 24.2
                }
            }
        }
    },



    "3622800": {
        "EventID": 3622800,
        "RaceNum": 2,
        "Meeting": "Albion Park",
        "RaceType": "H",
        "Description": "Seymour Rising Stars Championship C0 Heat One",
        "Distance": "1660m",
        "TrackCondition": "Good",
        "Weather": "Fine",
        "Abandoned": 0,
        "SuspendDateTime": "2014-06-17 15:09:10.0000000",
        "OutcomeDateTime": "2014-06-17 15:08:00.0000000",
        "EffectiveRaceDate": "2014-06-17",
        "Status": "Closed",
        "Results": [

        ],
        "Dividends": {
            "RunnerProducts": [

            ]
        }
    },



    "3679673": {
        "EventID": 3679673,
        "RaceNum": 6,
        "Meeting": "Thirsk",
        "RaceType": "T",
        "Description": "Market Cross Jewellers Handicap",
        "Distance": "1200m",
        "TrackCondition": null,
        "Weather": null,
        "Abandoned": 0,
        "SuspendDateTime": "2014-06-18 02:20:00.0000000",
        "OutcomeDateTime": "2014-06-18 02:20:00.0000000",
        "EffectiveRaceDate": "2014-06-17",
        "Status": "Open",
        "Results": [

        ],
        "Dividends": {
            "RunnerProducts": [

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse this using JSON.Net and i have tried this code.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var query =
    from JProperty ev in obj.AsJEnumerable()
    from JProperty evid in ev.Value.AsJEnumerable()
    let value = (JObject)evid.Value
    select new
    {
        Description = (string)value["Description"]

    };
```

I am getting this error "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'."

i also want to read event_id which is inside results and dividents. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Do you really think you need to post 384 lines of JSON to demonstrate this? Please put more effort into asking a question with a *minimal* set of data and code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I am sorry sir i have edit my code and my original json is in thousands. I tried to reduce in some lines of code but i have now reduced it more thanks

Comment: There's still over 100 lines of JSON. I suspect you could easily reproduce the problem with about 20 lines of JSON or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're getting the properties of the properties - and then trying to cast each of the values to `JObject`, and then taking the `Description` of *that*. That's one level too deep, as you have:

- The root object
- Each property of the root object, which genuinely has an object as its value
- Each property of each of those values... most of which are just string properties, so the value *can't* be cast to `JObject`

It's not clear why you're using `AsJEnumerable()` at all, but all you need is the properties of the root object, which is easily obtained with the `Properties()` method. Likewise it's not clear why you're using an anonymous type, rather than just getting a sequence of strings. This works fine:

```
var query =
    from ev in obj.Properties()
    select (string) ev.Value["Description"];
```

Or without the query syntax:

```
var query = obj.Properties.Select(ev => (string) ev.Value["Description"]);
```

Next:

> i also want to read event_id which is inside results and dividents

In the data you've given, that's always the same as the value of the `EventID` property in the top-level type. So you'd be better off with:

```
var query =
    from ev in obj.Properties()
    select new { Description = (string) ev.Value["Description"],
                 Id = (string) ev.Value["EventID"] };
```

If you really want to get at the values in the dividends and results, you'll need to work out how you'll handle the multiple entries in those properties.

Comment: The user here appears to be a continuation of the user of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254964/parsing-json-feed-using-json-net. This code here looks awfully familiar to me.

Comment: thanks and how can i get event_id which is inside Results and Dividents?

Comment: @user3747054: See my edit - it's easier to get it from the "main" object for each event rather than the one in results and dividends (not dividents, by the way - if you keep making that typo, you'll have trouble if you try to extract the property).

Comment: well i need other items for example final_dividend from dividends  and saddle_number from Results

Comment: @user3747054: Well now you're changing the question. When you ask a question on Stack Overflow, you should ask a *single* question and stop there, rather than adding on extra requirements as you go along. I've explained why you were getting that error, and helped you get the description and the event ID. If you're having trouble with something else, work on it yourself then ask a new question (ideally with a *much* smaller example JSON document, and a short but *complete* program).

Comment: thanks alot you helped me yesterday regarding my xml question and today you have solved my query thanks again