# EF Core 6 Unknown Error Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

While trying to implement CamelCase in Entity Framework Core 6 with .net 6 it's throwing unknowing errors as

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type
> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

**This is how I defined:**

```
entity.OwnsMany(n => n.Products).ToJsonProperty("products");

[JsonProperty("products")]
public ICollection<CustomProduct> Products { get; set; }
```

Even not able to implement CamelCase for the properties under the products collection

@Microsoft Why this Unknown error.
Why entity framework has no proper support/documentation for CosmosDb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON C# Parsing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256628/json-c-sharp-parsing-error)

Comment: CamelCase is not completely supported by the Microsoft Entity Framework library. If we used ToJsonProperty() Method there is a mismatch happening with data and the collection. But its throwing caste error.